# XML attributes does not get unmarshalled with JAXB 2 while using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've got my Java classes derived from XSD with XJC tool. Unmarshaling works fine with default settings. However I've switched to SAX parser implementation (from SAXSource here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) and now unnmarshalling is of course 2 times faster but XML attributes does not get unmarshalled. It means that attribute that is defined as

```
@XmlAttribute(required=true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
protected String messageId;
```

is set to `null`. In XML I have

```
<Message messageId="123">
...
</Message>
```

Everything else get unmarshalled properly.
I have this issue with all objects that uses attributes.

I have Apache Xerces implemetation of SAX parser.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that JAXB don't work properly with SAX parser unless parser is set to be namespace aware and correct namespaces are set. DOM parser works fine with namespace aware property set to false.

Comment: I had the same problem, added setNamespaceAware(true) to the factory and it solved the problem. Thanks